# Android & Bundles

Tags: android, bundle, oncreate

what is the difference between: myBundle & the one returned by getArguments()

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle myBundle) { //on create() belonging to a Fragment
    super.onCreate(myBundle);
    // So myBundle vs getArguments()
}
```

From my simple test they are not the same object, tested this with:

```
private void compareThem(Bundle myBundle, Bundle arguments) {
    Log.d("---myBundle==null: ", " " + (myBundle==null));
    Log.d("---arguments==null: ", " " + (arguments==null));

    if(myBundle!=null && arguments!=null) {
    Log.d("---myBundle==arguments: ", " " + (myBundle==arguments));
    Log.d("---myBundle.equals(arguments): ", " " + (myBundle.equals(arguments)));
    }
}
```

Sometimes I receive: false, true, false, false sometimes: false, false, false, false
Anyways.. ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bundle passed in `onCreate()` (myBundle in your code) is so called savedInstanceState. You can save some data ("state") from the fragment in the bundle in the method [`onSaveInstanceState()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onSaveInstanceState%28android.os.Bundle%29) and later this bundle will be available in `onCreate()` and in some other methods.

Bundle returned by [`getArguments()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#getArguments%28%29) method is the bundle passed from caller of the fragment. This bundle is provided via `setArguments()` method.